# How to assign a household (with its GPS latitude and coordinate) to a certain pixel of the .tif file in R-Studio

Tags: gps, satellite, rstudio, stata

I have a one-day composite flooding data downloaded from https://www.ssec.wisc.edu/flood-map-demo/ftp-link/ftp-link-viirsrealtime/ for a specific region (called viirs_max_01_2023.tif).
The pixels are 350x350 meters and I have households' gps coordinates in a Stata dataset.
I would like to assign each household to a certain pixel and the number of flooded days for that certain household during a month.

The next step is to create a 1-km-buffer from a household and to attach the number of flooded days for the household again to further advance with other research questions.

I have been trying it in "RStudio" with no significant progress. Any suggestion in "Stata" or "RStudio".

Comment: Read your tiff to R using `terra::rast()` function. Read in your Stata dataset to R. Convert stata dataset to either `spatVector` with `terra::vect()` function either `{sf}` object using `sf::st_as_sf()` function. Make sure both (raster and vector) have same CRS. Then use `terra::extract()` to read the flood values for your households coordinates (converted already to spatial object). Use either `terra::buffer()` or `sf::st_buffer()` to create buffers and reapply `terra::extract()`.